# Can't load prometheus.yml config file with docker (prom/prometheus)

Tags: docker, dockerfile, prometheus, prometheus-alertmanager

I am trying to load prometheus with docker using the following custom conf file: ***danilo@machine:/prometheus-data/prometheus.yml***:

```yaml
global:
  scrape_interval:     15s # By default, scrape targets every 15 seconds.

  # Attach these labels to any time series or alerts when communicating with
  # external systems (federation, remote storage, Alertmanager).
  external_labels:
    monitor: 'codelab-monitor'

  # A scrape configuration containing exactly one endpoint to scrape:
  # Here it's Prometheus itself.
scrape_configs:
  # The job name is added as a label `job=<job_name>` to any timeseries scraped from this config.
  - job_name: 'prometheus'

    # Override the global default and scrape targets from this job every 5 seconds.
    scrape_interval: 5s

    static_configs:
      - targets: ['localhost:9090']

      - targets: ['localhost:8083', 'localhost:8080']
        labels: my_app
      group: 'my_app_group'
```

With the following command:

```sh
$ sudo docker run -p 9090:9090 prom/prometheus --config.file=/prometheus-
  data/prometheus.yml
```

The file already exists. However, I am getting the following message:

> level=error ts=2018-09-26T17:45:00.586704798Z caller=main.go:617 err="error loading config from "/prometheus-data/prometheus.yml": couldn't load configuration (--config.file="/prometheus-data/prometheus.yml"): open /prometheus-data/prometheus.yml: no such file or directory"

I'm following this guide:

- https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/

What can I do to load this file correctly?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

By “the file already exists”, do you mean that the file is on your host at `/prometheus-data/prometheus.yml`? If so, then you need to bind mount it into your container for it to be accessible to Prometheus.

```
sudo docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /prometheus-data/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus
```

It's covered under [Volumes & bind-mount](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/installation/#volumes-bind-mount) in the documentation.

Answer (score 7):

I am using docker-compose.yaml and I also got the same issue. I had to set volume details as follows.

```
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus:v2.26.0
    user: root
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - /apps/prometheus/configs/prometheus.yaml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yaml
      - /data/prometheus:/prometheus
    command: --web.enable-lifecycle --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Answer (score 1):

I was doing the same and it works when put the whole path like whole path:

```
sudo docker run -p 9090:9090 -v User/inner-directories.../prometheus-data/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

When you use volumes you have to put paths that are registered on docker config resources

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue, and none of the above answers worked for me.
I received the following error:

```
docker run -d -p9090:9090 --name prometheus --network my-network -v ./prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus
docker: Error response from daemon: source /var/lib/docker/overlay2/36ea9303de63182ffed055cca6d7f59880400e03a29e3c1ecf770f80beb51f24/merged/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml is not directory.
```

I was using windows directory pneumonic "/" for prometheus unix os.

It started working after changing "/" with "\" for unix path and double quotes with "\\" for windows path

```
docker run -d -p9090:9090 --name prometheus --network my-network -v "D:\\projects\\docker\\prometheus.yml":/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus
```

Answer (score 0):

Youneed to mount volume on your docker . Solution of @Udara is good but with a mistake on command.

```
sudo docker run -p 9090:9090 -v /prometheus-data/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml prom/prometheus --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
```

Dont forget to add **prometheus.yml** file under the folder **/prometheus-data**